# How to make configuration specifications for a single file or more in Doxygen?

Tags: graph, doxygen, dot

I am currently building documentation with Doxygen for a C++ project.

Despite the magnificence of this tool, I have been looking for information for days about configuration options. Indeed, I am showing call and inheritance graphs for all classes by default and I successfully removed collaboration graphs for all classes with the following lines:

```
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = NO
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
```

The problem is that I would like to remove the inheritance graph for a specific class, but I can't find any option allowing this, locally or not.
I searched for special tags to put in my header file in order to specify configuration stuff, or even include doxygen configuration file(s) from the header (options INCLUDE/INCLUDE_PATH, but usable only from a configuration file...), but nothing seems to be good for my objective.
Some people already asked that kind of question in the past but never received any answer (eg. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890201/doxygen-hide-specific-elements-in-collaboration-diagram)).

I am aware that doing the contrary could be an option, meaning that I could disable every kind of graph in the main configuration file and then activate the graphs in the files/classes I want by using the \callgraph tag, but it would be very very annoying since I have a lot of files needing those graphs.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance !

Bests

Comment: What is the purpose?  There is no way to do this that I know of.  If the class is documented at all, it follows the rules set in Doxygen config.  If you are trying to do some very formal documentation, it would be helpful to learn TeX and use the LaTeX output.  You can then write TeX templates and use scripts to grab out parts of the output and replace them with your template.  This is way too much work though for anything but regulatory reasons.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore : Hello Denise, the purpose is quite simple : by default, I want my classes to have a call diagram. But for some few classes (let's say 1 out of 10, to get an idea of the scale), I don't want any call diagram. The reason is that those classes are very big and important ones, and so having a lot of calls in call diagrams : the diagrams are way too big, and my team and I decided to disable them for those specific classes. Here is the reason, tell me if I poorly spoke.

Comment: If you are disabling them for performance of Doxygen reasons, then my earlier suggestion will not work, it would add to the overhead, not help.  You could set up two separate doxygen configurations that include different source files and settings, but this would be difficult to maintain and you'd have to have two output locations to get everything indexed (but even then on two indexes.)

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore : Yep I understand what you're saying, but in fact it's more a "vision-friendly" reason : we don't need to display those calls for those specific classes, it's not the purpose of our Doxygen setup. So you're saying that I should patch my html files provided by Doxygen with LaTEX script(s) (which would remove call graphs) ? I was thinking about using .bat script(s) (I am working on Windows, by the way) to patch my html file after doxygen process, but it doesn't provide a good feeling.
But if patching is the only solution, why not !

Is that what you were thinking/talking about ?

Comment: No, you don't need LaTeX, you can patch the html directly.  Just make your script replace the unwanted graphic files in the output html folder with a single pixel graphic.  Or you can strip out the html that refers to the graphic.  You'll still spend a lot of time generating the graphs, but you can toss them out after they are generated.

Comment: I had LaTeX on the brain because I think of that when I think of the need for fancy formatting, but you're just looking for a small improvement, not really detailed formatting.

Comment: The other thing you could do with scripts is have two doxygen configurations with different files/settings, and then make a script that will merge the index files for the two sets of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the settings.

Turn off call graphs in your doxygen config, and in the classes where you want call graphs use the manual command:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcallgraph

Unfortunately this does not resolve the question for class graphs as there is no manual command for class graph.

You can make your own custom graphs with dot/graphviz, which is exactly what Doxygen is doing under the hood:
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddot

If doing this for a large project, you might want to make a script that can build and insert these simple graphs from the code for all files at once.  Then you can manually delete the ones you don't want after all.

Comment: So this is the only way of doing this ? (Excepted maybe post-processing html files patching)
If yes, it is quite annoying because as you say, there is a lot of files and only a few of them do not require graphs.
However, thank you for the answer !
(That's the kind of feature they could add in the next versions of Doxygen ; I mean, why whould there be only the disable all / enable one file at a time option ?)

Comment: You could contact them about commercial support if you wish: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/support.html